# Поле datepicker прячется за модальным окном

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, datepicker

Хочу использовать в модальном окне поле с выбором даты, для этого юзаю любой плагин datepicker, но сколько уже плагинов перепробовал у всех одна болезнь - при клике календарь появляется, но он перекрыт самим модальным окном, как это исправить? Может кто сталкивался с подобным, как это решается? Задавал различные z-index не помогает.

Comment: Вы задайте модальному окну `z-index:1`, а дате `z-index: 2`. Должно помочь

Comment: @Yuri Ну да это очевидно единственное решение. Как оказалось я просто не те z-index крутил((

Comment: Constantine Shibaev, бывает ))